# Spring modules application properties

Tags: java, spring, module, java-9, java-module

I need to create java modules for existing Spring application. I have no experience regarding modules, but so far I've gathered I require to migrate existing packages to new module in order for new modules to work. When I run the app I get the following message:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

I understand this is due to `application.properties`. How can I define global properties. I have created .yml in resource package of said module, but I still get the same error. 
Also in order to boot all the modules I require something like docker?

Comment: please ask your question in the title

Comment: Could you add more information, e.g. by providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of (an essential part of) your application?